# GNOME extension is incompatible

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, 21.10, extension

I used Ubuntu 20.04 for a few months. This is the third I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and I cannot install this GNOME extension: [Emoji Selector](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1162/emoji-selector/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: The extension needs an update to support Gnome 40, you can read the comments at the link you provided. Your only options are, update the extension yourself or wait for the author to do it. Looking at the github page https://github.com/maoschanz/emoji-selector-for-gnome it seems the author is still active.

Comment: Let's keep the answers to this question focussed on the general issue of incompatible GNOME extensions. We can post another question post about emoji selectors specifically, if needed.

Answer (score 5):

You are facing the major drawback of using Gnome Shell extensions from the Gnome Website. Gnome Shell unfortunately breaks extensions frequently. The author then needs to adapt the extension to mach the newer Gnome Shell version. If that does not happen, the user has a problem. There is nothing you can do except signalling the issue, and hoping the author will pick up, apart from going into coding yourself.

- You may prefer to install extensions from Ubuntu software. These are packed and tested to work with your desktop. This is a selection of extensions that is rather stable, although even there, there is no guarantee that an extension will be available in a next Ubuntu version.
- You may prefer to select a Long Term Release Ubuntu version. Such system is supported for a longer time, so you are less likely to have to adapt your workflow because some components you rely on stop working.
- Unsupported: you can force the extension to be loaded in your current version of Gnome Shell by changing the version number in the `metadata.json` file of the extension with a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for the issue of incompatible GNOME extensions, you can find other tools that perform the same function and that are independent of GNOME Shell.

For a specific example, there are alternatives to the Emoji Selector extension mentioned in the question post. If you open *Ubuntu Software* and search for `emoji picker` you'll find one such tool which you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to install a hibernation menu using the two extensions bellow:

- [Simpler Off Menu (Menu for Hibernation)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/)
- [Hibernate Status Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/)

In Firefox the slider of the button was set to the 'On' state and nothing was happening. After refreshing the page, the button was set again to the 'Off' the state.

After I updated Ubuntu using Software Updater and rebooted the system, I successfully enabled the needed extensions. The following things were required (I do not yet know the exact order and how many times some points should be repeated to take proper effect):

- Pressing the configuration button of the extension.
- Pressing again 'Off' then 'On' for disabling and enabling the extension.
- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Logging out and logging in.

After that the extensions were added to UI.

For installing GNOME extensions support, I used the instructions from this article: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/install-gnome-extensions-on-ubuntu

Here are the relevant steps from it:

1. Add the "GNOME Shell integration" add-on to the browser (Firefox or Chrome).
2. Install `chrome-gnome-shell` (also suitable for Firefox):

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
   ```
3. Installed Tweaks:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```

Here is a similar question: [Why does nothing happen when trying to install dash to dock extension?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376381/why-does-nothing-happen-when-trying-to-install-dash-to-dock-extension/1379232)