# Why does nothing happen when trying to install dash to dock extension?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to install extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/. I installed the addon for Firefox to load them from the browser, but when I turn the extension on, nothing happens. No error and no message at all.

I tried these things:

1. Install `gnome-shell-extensions`:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
   ```
2. Install `chrome-gnome-shell`:

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
   ```
3. After that I installed the GNOME Tweaks tool as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
4. Open the GNOME Tweaks tool as follows:

   ```
   gnome-tweaks
   ```

This happens while trying to install dash to dock (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/)

Comment: How does your question differ from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371533/gnome-extensions-is-incompitable) one?

Comment: I honestly don't know why I am getting only negative responses at this specific stackexchange site. I tried installing it manually as well but still didn't get any result as why I was brave enough to ask it here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you be a bit more specific and tell us which extensions you have problems with? If the extensions don't work, perhaps we can suggest alternatives that do. Please [edit] your question to add this info!

Comment: @kanehekili The question you linked is about 21.10 which introduced GNOME 40. This one is about 20.04 which uses GNOME 3.36. Hence they are different questions.

Comment: I tried installing dash to dock

Comment: When you clicked to install Dash to dock, did you get a pop up window and click *Install*? Is the extension showing in Tweaks -> *Extensions*?

Comment: Nope, I'm getting zero interaction when turning it on. It also doesn't appear in the tweaks extensions menu

Comment: ¹K.Gero - I apologize - My comment wasn't correct. I checked my installation: I did not install "dash to dock", but to get the extensions I installed the "browser extension" via the link you described. (I used Firefox). All "on" extensions can be seen in tweaks.

Comment: Maybe this could work: https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/download.html

Comment: After installing it via git it seems to appear, although now it says error loading extension next to it resulting in me not being able to do anything with it yet

Comment: K. Gero, you aren't using Firefox via Snap by any chance are you? My understanding is that the Snap version of Firefox does not support Gnome Extensions.

Comment: I'm using the default installed firefox, I tried it with chrome and got the same result (nothing) as well though

Comment: Can you install other extensions normally or does this problem only happen with Dash to dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone encounters this problem, I was able to solve it the following way:

1. First I removed the extension from everywhere so I made sure I'm starting out clean.
2. Then I downloaded the extension from it's GitHub repo via:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock.git
   ```
3. After all these, I installed the extension manually by doing the following:

   ```
   cd dash-to-dock
   git fetch --all
   git checkout origin/gnome-3.34
   ```

   (for me it was working with this 3.34 branch)

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```
4. Finally, I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entered `r`.

Comment: What do you mean with "from everywhere" in point 1? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks! Works!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379313/1548713) solved the similar problem.