# Where is working "Simpler Off Menu" gnome-shell extension for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: power-management, gnome-shell-extension, 22.04, extension, gnome-power-manager

For Ubuntu 20.04 extension can be installed from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/).
But for 22.04 it is not working. Where can I found working version and how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master project of the extension on gitlab is [here](https://gitlab.com/K3rcus/simpler-off-menu).
Version in master project is not working now on Ubuntu 22.04.

There is a fork of this project for Ubuntu 22.04: [Simpler Off Menu - support for Ubuntu 22.04](https://gitlab.com/sunkrop/simpler-off-menu-support-for-ubuntu-22-04)

**Description**:

- This version will work only with Ubuntu 22.04 (also may be with 21.10, and may be with future versions).
- "Power Off" button handler changed to "systemctl poweroff" instead of standard Ubuntu's handler with confirmation.
- Added "Reboot" button with handler "systemctl reboot".
- Handler for "Suspend" button changed to "systemctl suspend".
- "Hibernate" button handler changed from "systemctl hibernate" to "sudo systemctl hibernate" since this command requires sudo permissions. "systemctl hibernate" need to add to sudoers list (sudo visudo, user    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate) to remove user confirmation for performing the command.
- Added separators between buttons.
- To the file "extension_rus.js" added (hard coded) Russian translations for not localized menu items (Reboot, Hibernate). To apply translations this file should be used instead of "extension.js" (need to rename extension_rus.js to extension.js). In the future it is better to support proper localization approach.
- "shell-version" in "metadata.json" file changed from
  "shell-version": ["3.36"]
  to
  "shell-version": ["3.36","3.37","3.38","40.0","41.0","42.0","43.0","44.0","45.0","46.0","47.0","48.0","49.0","50.0"]
  to support Ubuntu 22.04 and other releases. There is no way to specify "all" versions as supported. Because of this many of possible versions were listed. 42.0 means Ubuntu 22.04. 3.36 means Ubuntu 20.04.
- In "prefs.js" file constructor for new Gtk.Grid(...) replaced on empty constructor and setter methods since constructor with parameters is missed in GTK for Ubuntu 22.04. Backwords compatibility is not yet supported. In the future it is also recommended to support case for Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: Screen]

**How to install it?**

- Manually download files of the extension (`metadata.json`, `extension.js`, `prefs.js`)
  from [the fork](https://gitlab.com/sunkrop/simpler-off-menu-support-for-ubuntu-22-04)
  and put them to

`/home/<your_user_name>/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/SimplerOffMenu.kerkus@pm.me/`

- Perform [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371533/gnome-extension-is-incompatible/1379313#1379313) for configuring gnome-shell-extensions support.
- Install `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`
- Activities -> type `Extensions` and press `Enter`
- Enable `SimplerOffMenu` extension in `Extensions` menu
- If extension is not applied perform `Alt + F2`, `r`, `Enter` or logout and login again.