# How to poweroff / reboot / suspend / hibernate Ubuntu 22.04 by two mouse clicks (not four as by default)?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, reboot, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-power-manager

How to remove confirmation menu when performing poweroff / reboot / suspend / hibernate actions? How to place this menu items without submenus?

In Ubuntu 20.04 I used ["Simpler Off Menu" gnome-shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/) but in Ubuntu 22.04 it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Ubuntu 22.04 "Simpler Off Menu" gnome-shell extension can be installed as described in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406173/1548713).